# Some functionality not working in "Release" deploy (but working in "Debug")

Tags: ios, debugging, deployment, xamarin, release

I Have been working on an iOS app, with which (down-to-earth) I send to and receive data from a database. I am currently in the alpha state, where we want to deploy the app as a "Release", and have a group of people test the app to receive feedback e.t.c. There's a few problems though.

When deploying the app as "Release" to an iPad 2 (iOS 8.0.2), some functionality stops working that worked before when deploying the app as "Debug". Things like:

- the LoadingOverlays (http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/) stop working (it appears, but right after that, it disappears again, leaving you with a grey screen with no text. The functionality continues to run though, and works as intended.)
- The URLs to the database (and the user-repository) stopped working, and make the app crash (I can't debug that, since It was deployed as "Release").

What's even more weird, is when I deploy the app as "Debugg", use the login functionality to log into the app, quit the app and re-upload the app as "Release", it logs in successfully (using the NSUserDefaults for username and password).

I don't know if this is a bug, or I am missing something about the differences between "Debug" and "Release"? Maybe it's an iOS version-bug of some kind? I really have no clue.

Any help is much appreciated.

With dear regards,
Björn Broer

Comment: This is not what I was asking. But your advice will be looked at in a later stage.

Comment: I suspect that you have some linker problems. See: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Comment: That's it! After tweaking with the project settings, all functionalities now do their thing! Thanks a lot Martijn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to fix the "Linker" settings of your project. See the Xamarin documentation: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/